# How to know when exactly FirebaseApp.configure() is done?

Tags: ios, firebase

Before using Firebase SDK, we must run the code

```
 FirebaseApp.configure()
```

The documentation says it will throw an error if something fails, but it returns nil, and I don't know how can I know exactly when it will be done.

Comment: @Sweeper That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson Posted now.

Comment: I thought it's async :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseApp.html#/c:objc(cs)FIRApp(cm)configure) of `configure`:

> Configures the default Firebase app with the provided options. The
>   default app is named __FIRAPP_DEFAULT. Raises an exception if any
>   configuration step fails. This method is thread safe.

It says that "This method is thread safe and contains *synchronous* file I/O", which means its job will be finished before the next line executes, as opposed to something that's *asynchronous*, like `UIViewController.present(_:animated:completion:)`, which might not complete presenting the VC before the next line executes.